# Possessive adjectives where one noun is singular and the other is plural

Tags: gramática

I wanted to ask a question about the usage of possessive adjectives.

Consider the following sentence in English

> I play with my brother and dogs.

I am using a singular noun (brother) and plural noun (dogs) which are preceded by only one possessive adjective.

I attemped to write this in Spanish:

> Yo juego con mi hermano y mis perros.

But I was wondering whether it was possible to do something like English where only possessive adjective precedes both nouns, where the first is singular and the second is plural:

> Yo juego con mi hermano y perros.

Is this correct usage of grammar in Spanish?

Comment: To be honest I think your proposed English sentence sounds unnatural. I would assume that the dogs belonged to someone else.

Comment: Your English sentence is not correct without a pronoun (“some dogs”) or a second possessive adjective (“my / his dogs”).

Answer (score 1):

For your question, no, it just does not work like that.
 it is different than in English.

In Spanish, for possessive adverbs  **there has to be a correspondence between the number and gender of the things being owned.** (`hermana mía, hermano mio, mis hermanas y hermanos`) [see more about usage here](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/pronombres-y-determinantes/posesivos)

Hence, your first example is right and should be used

> [Yo] juego con mi hermano y mis perros.